# Converting Time Series Values Back into Dates R

Tags: r, date, time-series

Hi I am creating an R time series, but after modeling, I need to convert the column back to date I can actually interpret (yyyy-mm-dd).

```
bus_date <- as.Date(c('2017-04-01', '2017-04-08', '2017-04-15', '2017-04-22', '2017-04-29'))
sales <- c(100, 110, 110, 130, 120)

sales_data <- data.frame(bus_date, sales)

sales_data.ts <- ts(sales_data$sales, 
                       start = min(sales_data$bus_date),
                       freq = (365.25/7))
sales_data.ts
```

I have tried using some of the functions in lubridate (this worked when i had daily data like 2015.123, 2015.456, etc) but not working....what am I missing here?  How can I get the dates back?

```
setDT(data_ARIMA, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
data_ARIMA$dates_intermediate <- date_decimal(as.numeric(data_ARIMA$rn))
data_ARIMA$dates <- as.Date(date_decimal(as.numeric(data_ARIMA$rn)))
data_ARIMA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency you using are may not be appropriate for your data. Try this

```
sales_data.ts <- ts(sales_data$sales, 
                    start = min(sales_data$bus_date),
                    frequency = 1/7) #OR deltat = 7
sales_data.ts
#Time Series:
#Start = 17257 
#End = 17285 
#Frequency = 0.142857142857143 
#[1] 100 110 110 130 120

as.Date(as.numeric(time(sales_data.ts)))
#[1] "2017-04-01" "2017-04-08" "2017-04-15" "2017-04-22" "2017-04-29"
```